# Stop Using iCloud for Photos

Tags: iphone, icloud, privacy

For a long time, I used Adobe Lightroom to store my photos.  Then I got lazy, and a lot of the images I took with my iPhone, just got left on the phone.  So I started to use iCloud, which meant that if I wanted to manipulate a photo on the Mac, I didn't have to import it.

Then came the announcement by Apple that they were going to start scanning photos.  None of mine are in any way, shape or form illegal (unless you count photos of our cats and of my motorcycle), but I don't like the idea of a company looking at them.

So basically, I'd like to get all of my photos off of the iPhone (and off of iCloud), onto my Mac, so I can start to import them into LR.  There are thousands of them, so it's going to be a long process, but sooner I start, sooner it's done.

Can someone tell me how I do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Turn off the copy to iCloud first.

Comment: OK, done that.  What next?

Comment: Copy all the photos from iCloud to your Mac. And uncheck iCloud photos in your iCloud account preferences.

Comment: It's easier to export them from Photos first, and then disable iCloud Photos. Otherwise exporting them will be a pain.